# Magento AND/OR combination model filter

Tags: mysql, magento, orm

Hi created a custom model inside Magento(resource is based on Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract ). Everything works pretty much fine.
I tried to make a filter on table, that would output the following *where* clause:

```
where
  product_id = 1
  and ((customer_id = 0 and customergroup_id = 2) or (customergroup_id = 0 and customer_id = 3))
  and ((productgroup_id = 0 and product_class = 8) or (product_class = 0 and productgroup_id = 4))
```

Any idea on how to do that using *addFilter* or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addFieldToFilter`/`addAttributeToFilter` methods are not well suited for a query *that* complex. You will have to construct your query by hand:

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->where('product_id = ?', 1)
    ->where(sprintf(
        '((customer_id = %d AND customergroup_id = %d) OR (customer_id = %d AND customergroup_id = %d))',
        0, 2, 3, 0))
    ->where(sprintf(
        '((productgroup_id = %d AND product_class = %d) OR (productgroup_id = %d AND product_class = %d))',
        0, 8, 4, 0));
```